# ValueError at /accounts/signup/

Tags: python, django

this is my signup view ->

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        print('hello')
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)

            account = Account(user=user)
            account.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/gallery/index')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

this is my accounts model ->

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, 
    related_name="profile",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="followers",null=True,blank=True)
```

this is the error I am getting -

> The view accounts.views.signup didn't return an HttpResponse object.
>   It returned None instead.

I am getting this error whenever I submit the form. I am using the django admin signup form by default

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
def signup(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        print('hello')
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)

            account = Account(user=user)
            account.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/gallery/index')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```